# How to pass long string value variable in a Doc file using beanshell post processor in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, export-to-csv, nsregularexpression

The following is the code, I have added in my Beanshell Post Processor:

import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

String path=FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();

```
String var1= vars.get("Others");      
String var2= vars.get("Recommendations");

 f = new FileOutputStream("C://apache-jmeter-5.4.1/apache-jmeter- 
 5.4.1/bin/Output_IndustryType.csv",true);
 p = new PrintStream(f); 

 this.interpreter.setOut(p); 

 p.println(var1+ "," +var2);

 f.close();
```

But the problem is that the value obtained from these two variables, is a long text, so in the CSV file it is coming in each column as a single text.
And value of Var1, is not coming in the CSV file, and when checked using Degub Sampler it is extracted properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating and it might be the case it will resolve your issue
2. If you plan to run your test with > 1 thread (virtual user) the approach is not valid at all as you will be getting random failures and unexpected behaviour due to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when 2+ threads will be concurrently writing into the same file so it makes more sense to consider declaring these `Others` and `Recommendations` guys as [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) and store them into the CSV file using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) plugin